# How to prevent spaces changing into + symbol in Lighting Components? when using EncodingUtil.urlEncode

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

**Apex Controller**

```
String abc = 'Roger\'O Silva';
        abc = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(abc, 'UTF-8');
```

**Lightning Component**

```
var name = decodeURIComponent(abc);
```

**output from lightning component**

[image: apace]
Space is replaced with + symbol

Comment: why dont you encode/decode on the client? otherwise, you can use the .replace() method

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the content you are encoding is some data and not any URL.

An alternate approach would be to use [EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueof(content))](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_base64Encode) to encode and [atob(encodedContent)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) in js to get the content back.

**Apex**

```
String content = '';
String encodedContent = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueof(content));
```

**JS**

```
const content = atob(encodedContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `EncodingUtil.urlEncode()` encodes data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which includes replacing space with + (and + with %2B btw).

As you can read at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid a + is a perfectly valid character for an URI. Therefore decoding an URI component which contains a `+` will result in a `+`. Not so with `urlencoded` forms.

If you are only concerned with the space/+ issue, you have to replace that character in your apex controller:

```
String abc = 'Roger\'O Silva';
abc = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(abc, 'UTF-8');
abc = abc.replace ('+', '%20');
```

`%20` is a perfectly valid URI **and** URL representation of a space. Then `decodeURIComponent()` will show the correct spaces.